# Parábolas e hipérbolas en Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

recientemente he estado intentando graficar parábolas con matplotlib y numpy, sin embargo he tenido algunos problemas y me gustaría saber como se podría hacer eso, sobre todo tengo dudas sobre el sentido de la parábola, ¿como se configura su orientación (para que abra en determinada dirección)?.
Gracias por su ayuda y disculpe si no me expliqué bien.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 1000)
y = x**2 
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Este código es lo que llevo hasta el momento, pero es más una función cuadrática que una parábola, sin olvidar la definición de parábola, que yo no respeto en ese código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quiere que la parábola abra hacia arriba, no ponga un signo negativo antes de la término cuadrado. Y al contrario, pongalo si quiere la parábola abra hacia abajo. Por ejemplo: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-x%5E2